# Is Quartz 2D the right choice for iPad Game

Tags: iphone, quartz-2d

I need to make a game with a tool bar of shapes that can be dragged on screen with the following functionality

1. shapes can be copied
2. shapes can be stretched and resized
3. shapes can be rotated
4. shape color can change
5. shapes can be cut in half and each half is now its own shape

is Quartz 2D the right way to approach this?

Comment: Which was your approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to better specify your game features,

I'm assuming your whole game is in Quarz 2D and that it's for iPad.

I have two opinions about it:

1) If you don't need UIKit ( tables, buttons, and other features ), I would go 100% OpenGL ES, if you plan to make a whole game out of Quarz 2D, and you plan real-time scaling, drag and drop, etc... I think your frame rate will suffer a lot less using OpenGL ES.

2) If you need UIKit , and your game is heavily UIKit based, Quarz2D could have a place in there, I think Quarz2D is best suited for animations/effects into UIKit rich applications ( see "Reeder" and the official "Twitter" application), those apps are empowered by Quarz2D and UIkit.